# Spring REST service returns HTTP 400 status

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have a REST service written with the Spring Framework v 3.2.0

Here is the Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/volunteer")
public class VolunteerController { 

    //several methods not included (all HTTP GET & working properly)

    @RequestMapping(value="/{volunteerId}/assignments/{sessionId}", 
                    method=RequestMethod.PUT, params={"worked"})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void setWorkedFlag(@PathVariable int volunteerId, 
                              @PathVariable int sessionId, 
                              @RequestParam int worked) {
        assignmentMapper.setWorked(volunteerId, sessionId, worked);
    }
}
```

When I submit a PUT request with this URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/volunteer/298/assignments/1?worked=true
```

I get a 400 restonse with the message : The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

I can also confirm that the underlying resource has not need modified.

I have compared the annotations against the request URL and can't see anything obviously wrong. Also, the other methods (omitted here) all work correctly, so the Application Context has been set up OK.

Any ideas?

Comment: `true` cannot be converted to `int`... HTTP is string only and Spring now tries to convert a `String` to an `int`. Whereas you, probably, think that it is a `boolean` which gets converted to an `int`.

Comment: To quote Homer Simpson : D'OH!

Comment: I guess one of you should post it as an answers, so it could be properly accepted for others' use...